# No parameter checking in GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I have written a C program, which consists below given three files in same directory

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
        int b=0;
        b = test_add(3,2);
        printf("Added: b=%d\n\n",b);
        return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
int test_add(int a, int b);
```

test.c

```
int test_add(int a, int b, int c)
{
        return a+b+c;
}
```

I am compiling the program using below command:

```
$gcc -Wall -Wextra main.c test.c
```

It compiles successfully. I can see there is mismatch in number of arguments of calling function and its actual definition. Compiler doesn't give any warning/error for such problem. How can this type of errors be reported by compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows one of the oddities of the C standard. It allows entities such as functions to be undefined.

The actual error is that you did not

```
#include "test.h"
```

in you `test.c` file.

That means that the main file only sees the version of the function with three parameters. When it reaches the function call, it implicitly declares the function with two parameters.

When you run it, you get bogus values for `b`. I am guessing the superuser's password could somehow be in there ;)

If you add the include directive, you get an error at compile time.

What worries me, that there is no warning, not even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: It cannot warn because there is nothing "against the law" during the compilation. The `main()` sees the declaration with two parameters and the call for "test_add" is indeed with 2 parameters. `test.c` is not aware about any other declaration of `test_add` except for the one which is implemented inside itself. The actual problem begins at the linkage process. In C, unlike C++, the function parameters are not part of the function name inside the binary object so linker successfully links `test_add` from `main()` to `test_add` from `test.c`.

Comment: That explains it. Still: Is there no way, the linker could look into the parameter list?

Comment: In C unfortunately no. The linker doesn't see the source code, only the binary which doesn't contain this information.

Comment: That's why you need `extern "C"` in order to use C functions in C++.